# Converting SPA to a SCORM 1.2 PACKAGE

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application, scorm, scorm1.2, scorm-cloud-api

I've recently been asked to check out whether it's possible to convert a React SPA into a SCORM 1.2 compliant package.

From my understanding, it is possible to reference a HTML page and relevant assets in the xml:

```
<resources>
  <resource identifier="r1" type="webcontent" adlcp:scormType="sco" href="index.html">
    <file href="index.html" />
    <file href="main.js" />
  </resource>
</resources>
```

But it seems there wouldn't be any ability to handle an SPA that was built with routing?

**A side question**: Is there a spec similar to `<folder>` so that we don't have to define each asset?

Answer (score 0):

Do you only want to launch your spa from within the LMS without any tracking?
Than you should use the adlcp:scormType="asset".

Else your content would have to support the whole mandatory sco communication features like:

- find the scorm api
- initialize the session
- get and set values
- errorhandling
- finalize the session